# How to remove persistent bottom navigation bar from some specific routes?

Tags: dart, flutter

I wanted to have persistent bottom navigation bar across my whole app so after searching for couple of hours I found a solution. 
I was inspired from this blog post and wrote my solution code [Flutter — navigating off the charts](https://medium.com/@swav.kulinski/flutter-navigating-off-the-charts-e118562a36a5)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './login/login.dart';
import './alerts/alerts.dart';
import './home/home.dart';
import './Theme.dart';
import './settings/settings.dart';
import './enroll/enroll.dart';
import './add_device/add_device.dart';
import './eachDevice/index.dart';
import './device_settings/device_settings.dart';
import 'splash_screen/splash_screen.dart';
import './geofences/geofence_list.dart';
import './geofences/draw_geofence.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import './home/second_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
void main() {
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigator = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  HttpOverrides.global = new AppHttpOverrides();
  Map<String, WidgetBuilder> _routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    "/alerts": (BuildContext context) => new Alerts(),
    "/login": (BuildContext context) => new LoginPage(),
    "/settings": (BuildContext context) => new Settings(),
    "/enroll": (BuildContext context) => new Enroll(),
    "/add_device": (BuildContext context) => new AddDevice(),
    "/history": (BuildContext context) => new History(),
    "/home": (BuildContext context) => new Home(),
    "/device_settings": (BuildContext context) => new DeviceSettings(),
    "/geofence_list": (BuildContext context) => new GeofenceList(),
    "/draw_geofence": (BuildContext context) => new DrawGeofence(),
  };

  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    navigatorKey: navigator,
    home: new SplashScreen(),
    builder: (context, child) {
      return new Scaffold(
          body: child,
          bottomNavigationBar:myBottomNavigationBar(),
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false
      );
    },
    theme: buildTheme(),
    routes: _routes,
  ));
}
```

This code works perfectly and I have static bottom navigation bar in all app pages however I want to exclude bottom navigation bar in some routes like login page how can I exclude bottom navigation bar for some specific pages with this approach.

Comment: hey, @Deniel did you find an answer or not. I am getting the same issue.
Thanks

Comment: @JigarFumakiya unfortunately I could't find any answer the only solution I found was using CupertinoTabScaffold or otherwise handle all of your pages inside one scaffold widget and don't use flutter navigator and implement custom one for yourself to handle such scenarios

Comment: okay, thanks for a quick reply.

Comment: Hi, I have the same case like yours @Daniel.V Have you found any solution till now ?

Comment: @JigarFumakiya did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 7):

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new LoginActivity()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a variable `bool isBottomNavBarToBeShown`. You can use some kind of function for the body in `Scaffold` like

```
  _getScreen(route) {
    switch (route) {
      case 'route1':
        return Route1();
        break;

      case 'route2':
        return Route2();
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

but in your case, you have to change

```
  "/login": (BuildContext context) => new LoginPage(),
```

to

```
      "/login": (BuildContext context) { 
               return new LoginPage();
              },
```

now just set

```
    setState(() {
      isBottomNavBarToBeShown=false;
    });
```

e.g.

```
case 'route1':
setState(() {
      isBottomNavBarToBeShown=false;
    });
return Route1();
break;
```

in your case

```
    "/login": (BuildContext context) { 
               setState(() {
               isBottomNavBarToBeShown=false;
               });
               return new LoginPage();
             },
```

so in your `Scaffold`

`bottomNavigationBar:myBottomNavigationBar(),`
just use `bottomNavigationBar:isBottomNavBarToBeShown ? myBottomNavigationBar() : null,`

First, create a `Stateful` screen first and add this in `Scaffold`.
So you can access `setState`

Please update on this, if it works for you.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work when setState called inside route build function app crash and give me this error setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build

Comment: as I say, you have to create a Stateful widget screen to use setState. It will help you to maintain and manipulate the screens. If you have to use only in this code do not use setState instead directly set value to true or false. but I think it will not help, give it a try. There are some ways to implement routes. I prefer to dynamically change screens rather creating a routes map.

Comment: I created a stateful widget and pass it to run app function inside this widget I put my codes and when routes changed and setState called it gives me error setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build furthermore if I change the value directly without setState it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Declare `variable` for `bottomNavigationBar` `content` like as

```
var navContent;
```

Create method for the exclude your bottomNavigationBar

```
excludeBottomNavigationBar(){
    return Container(
      height: 0.0,
    );
  }
```

Now, you need to assign the bottomNavigationBar content according your requirement, exclude bottomNavigationBar for the login page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import './login/login.dart';
  import './alerts/alerts.dart';
  import './home/home.dart';
  import './Theme.dart';
  import './settings/settings.dart';
  import './enroll/enroll.dart';
  import './add_device/add_device.dart';
  import './eachDevice/index.dart';
  import './device_settings/device_settings.dart';
  import 'splash_screen/splash_screen.dart';
  import './geofences/geofence_list.dart';
  import './geofences/draw_geofence.dart';
  import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
  import './home/second_navigation_bar.dart';
  import 'dart:io';
  import 'package:path/path.dart';
  void main() {
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigator = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
    HttpOverrides.global = new AppHttpOverrides();
    var navContent;

    excludeBottomNavigationBar(){
      return Container(
        height: 0.0,
      );
    }

    Map<String, WidgetBuilder> _routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      "/alerts": (BuildContext context){
        navContent = myBottomNavigationBar();
        new Alerts();
      },
      "/login": (BuildContext context){
        navContent = excludeBottomNavigationBar();
        new LoginPage();
      },
      "/settings": (BuildContext context){
        navContent = myBottomNavigationBar();
        new Settings();
      },
      "/enroll": (BuildContext context){
        navContent = myBottomNavigationBar();
        new Enroll();
      },
      "/add_device": (BuildContext context){
        navContent = myBottomNavigationBar();
        new AddDevice();
      },
      "/history": (BuildContext context){
        navContent = myBottomNavigationBar();
        new History();
      },
      "/home": (BuildContext context){
        navContent = myBottomNavigationBar();
        new Home();
      },
      "/device_settings": (BuildContext context){
        navContent = myBottomNavigationBar();
        new DeviceSettings()
      },
      "/geofence_list": (BuildContext context){
        navContent = myBottomNavigationBar();
        new GeofenceList()
      },
      "/draw_geofence": (BuildContext context){
        navContent = myBottomNavigationBar();
        new DrawGeofence()
      },
    };

    runApp(new MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigator,
      home: new SplashScreen(),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return new Scaffold(
            body: child,
            bottomNavigationBar:navContent,
            resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false
        );
      },
      theme: buildTheme(),
      routes: _routes,
    ));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution it was interesting, however, I tried your solution but it's not working all the time I tested and figure it out sometimes when navigating from one page to another material app builder function not called so new value of navContent won't be affected.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding an instance constructor to my main state widget.

```
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _currentIndex = 0;

  static MyAppState instance = new MyAppState._();
  MyAppState._();

  // (Excluded Build and page routes)

  Widget buildBottomNavigationBar(context) =>
      BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          _buildBottomNavigationBarItem("A", Icons.add),
          _buildBottomNavigationBarItem("B", Icons.remove),
        ],
        onTap: onTabTapped,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      );

  _buildBottomNavigationBarItem(name, icon) =>
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(icon), title: Text(name));

  //Routing for BottomNavigationBar
  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
      // Navigate ...
    });
  }
}
```

Then you can declare bottomNavigationBar in any screen you want by adding this line to the desired Scaffold.

```
bottomNavigationBar: MyAppState.instance.buildBottomNavigationBar(context)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue when using persistent_bottom_nav_bar | Flutter Package you can use the below snippet when you logout out of the app or when you perform something similar to that( (route) => false, in cases where you want to remove the backstak).

This example code assumes you pressed log out from one of your screens and the bottom nav bar gets duplicated when you log in again.

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushAndRemoveUntil(
    Navigation.getRoute(const LoginScreen()),
        (route) => false,
);`
```